# Find an R package on GitHub easily

Tags: r, github, package, cran

How can I find R packages easily on GitHub? Like on CRAN with

https://www.r-pkg.org/

I would like to find R packages for optimization on GitHub.

I've tried this:

[image: search - github 2]

Comment: Are you familiar with this CRAN taskview? https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html Many of the packages listed there host the source code on GitHub.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see rampl [rampl](https://github.com/skranz/rampl) and ompr [ompr](https://github.com/dirkschumacher/ompr)

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/

Answer (score 1):

if you do want to find package on GitHub and not on CRAN, I suggest you can filter the languages and add key word 'package' after your key words, hope it useful.